# Sqlalchemy database int to python enum

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have lots of integers in my existing database which signify an enum. In my python project I have created the corresponding enums like so:

```
class Status(Enum):
    OK = 0
    PENDING = 1
    CANCELED = 2
    DUPLICATE = 3
    INCOMING = 4
    BLOCKED = 5
```

In my SQLalchemy models I'd like to be able to do the following

```
status = Column(Status, nullable=False)
```

Which should convert the database integers to python enums and back transparantly

So far I've tried to inherit from the sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator and overwrite the process_bind_param and process_result_value to cast the int back and forwards.

This would however mean I would have to repeat this for every Enum in violation of the DRY principle.

I would thus prefer a Mixin class which inherits sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator and overwrites the two methods to cast to and from the Enum which inherits this mixin.

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: There exists a very well defined recipe to solve this problem by none other than the creator of sqlalchemy himself: http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2011/01/14/the-enum-recipe/

Answer (score 8):

The `TypeDecorator` can simply take the enum type as an argument.

```
class EnumAsInteger(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):
    """Column type for storing Python enums in a database INTEGER column.

    This will behave erratically if a database value does not correspond to
    a known enum value.
    """
    impl = sqlalchemy.types.Integer # underlying database type

    def __init__(self, enum_type):
        super(EnumAsInteger, self).__init__()
        self.enum_type = enum_type

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        if isinstance(value, self.enum_type):
            return value.value
        raise ValueError('expected %s value, got %s'
            % (self.enum_type.__name__, value.__class__.__name__))

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        return self.enum_type(value)

    def copy(self, **kwargs):
        return EnumAsInteger(self.enum_type)


class MyTable(Base):
    status = sqlalchemy.Column(EnumAsInteger(Status), nullable=False)
```

One thing you may need to consider is how to deal with unknown enum values in the database. The above solution will simply throw `ValueError` when such values are seen, e.g. during a query.

Comment: What if one would set `nullable=True`, will not this lead to `ValueError` exception?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ChoiceType`](https://sqlalchemy-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_types.html#module-sqlalchemy_utils.types.choice) from `SQLAlchemy-Utils`.

```py
status = Column(ChoiceType(Status, impl=db.Integer()), nullable=False)
```

This maps the column to an integer type on the database side.