# SQLAlchemy Enum type field with integer value

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

There is an events model in which I want to add a memebers_count field to indicate the number of participants. The user will make a single selection from the select form. I am using Enum type for this. The model looks like this

```
class MembersQuantity(enum.Enum):
    two = 2
    three = 3
    four = 4
    five = 5
    six = 6
    ...
    nineteen = 19
    twenty = 20
    thirty = 30
    forty = 40
    fifty = 50
    unlimited = 1000

events = Table(
    "events",
    metadata,
    Column("id", Integer(), primary_key=True),
    ...
    Column("members_count", Enum(MembersQuantity, values_callable=lambda obj: [e.value for e in obj]),
           nullable=False,
           default=MembersQuantity.two.value,
           server_default=MembersQuantity.two.value),
    ....
```

An error appears in the console when this entry is made

```
  File "/home/jekson/Projects/own/wplay/./models/events.py", line 64, in <module>
    Column("members_count", Enum(MembersQuantity, values_callable=lambda obj: [e.value for e in obj]),
  File "<string>", line 2, in __init__
  File "/home/jekson/virtualenvs/wplay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/deprecations.py", line 139, in warned
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jekson/virtualenvs/wplay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1383, in __init__
    self._enum_init(enums, kw)
  File "/home/jekson/virtualenvs/wplay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1425, in _enum_init
    length = max(len(x) for x in self.enums)
  File "/home/jekson/virtualenvs/wplay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/sqltypes.py", line 1425, in <genexpr>
    length = max(len(x) for x in self.enums)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I assumed the problem was that `[e.value for e in obj]` should be str instead of int and replaced it with `[str(e.value) for e in obj]` but got another error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be of the type '<class 'str'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<class 'int'>'
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is what do you want to persist? `two` or 2 or `<MembersQuantity.two: 2>`?

SQLAlchemy [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.Enum) states:

```
Above, the string names of each element, e.g. “one”, “two”, “three”, are persisted to the database; 
the values of the Python Enum, here indicated as integers, are not used;
the value of each enum can therefore be any kind of Python object whether or not it is persistable.
```

So if you have integer values of enum, you probably should have something like this:

```py
    Column(
       "members_count", 
       Enum(MembersQuantity),
       nullable=False,
       default=MembersQuantity.two.name,
       server_default=MembersQuantity.two.name
    )
```

The `name` attribute is `two`, while `value` attribute is 2 in your case. But you persist only left-hand side strings.
You should use `values_callable` only if you want to persist values instead of names, but docs states also: `value_callables - a callable which will be passed the PEP-435 compliant enumerated type, which should then return a list of string values to be persisted`. So you can persist value only if it is a string.

Here is a topic that can be helpful: [How to use Enum with SQLAlchemy and Alembic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47206201/how-to-use-enum-with-sqlalchemy-and-alembic)

Comment: Same result as in my question
`sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Argument 'arg' is expected to be one of type '<class 'str'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.ClauseElement'>' or '<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.elements.TextClause'>', got '<class 'int'>` So, easiest way is set values as string I think. I have made sure that using `int` in `enum` is inappropriate

Comment: Here you can find a hack for `int`: https://michaelcho.me/article/using-python-enums-in-sqlalchemy-models

Comment: You gave me great advice, found a solution that works for me in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38786737/9262339